# How do I arrange my android UI to realize a UI prototype design

Tags: android, ui-design

A UI designer has already done a design and a prototype that I am attempting to reproduce in code. I have something but I am wondering how to make my input widget look exactly like the activation code input in the prototype as well as containerize it in a way that it will have the white background that is overlayed on the parent's black background.

The design for the screen is here @ https://imagebin.ca/v/3tpl23ZiTWok.

The code for the UI that I have at the moment is:

> Activate Profile Screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="media.client.clientmediaandroid.activity.activateprofile.ActivateProfileActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_activateprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_activateprofile_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Activate Profile"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_activateprofile"/>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_activateprofile"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview_activateprofile_title">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="56dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="257dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_activateprofile_prompt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Type in the code that was sent to your phone"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_activateprofile_code"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Code"
                    android:inputType="number|numberPassword" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar_activateprofile_progress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        <!-- Activate Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/button_activateprofile_activate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Activate" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I will be grateful for help with this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to realize the closest functional design by removing the ScrollView from the layout. The new layout is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context="media.client.clientmediaandroid.activity.activateprofile.ActivateProfileActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_activateprofile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/clientPrimaryBlue"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_activateprofile_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Activate Profile"
        android:textColor="@color/highlightColor"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar_activateprofile" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_activateprofile_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="56dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_activateprofile_prompt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Type in the code that was sent to your phone"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/clientPrimaryBlue">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_activateprofile_code"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Code"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar_activateprofile_progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/clientPrimaryBlue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <!-- Activate Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/button_activateprofile_activate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_app_bg"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Activate"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Colleague working on the iOS app realized the code input control by creating a custom control. I will look into this later on.

Thank you very much.